# Parsing positional arguments

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

Consider the following trivial program adopted from the boost program options [examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/program_options/tutorial.html#id2083241)

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <boost/version.hpp>

#include <iostream>

int
main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    namespace po = boost::program_options;

    po::options_description desc("Options");

    unsigned foo;
    desc.add_options()
        ("help,h", "produce help message")
        ("foo", po::value(&foo), "set foo") 
        ;

    po::variables_map vm;
    try {
        po::store(
                po::parse_command_line( argc, argv, desc ),
                vm
                );
        po::notify( vm );

        if ( vm.count("help") ) {
            std::cout << desc << "\n";
            std::cout << "boost version: " << BOOST_LIB_VERSION << std::endl;
        }
    } catch ( const boost::program_options::error& e ) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

the following behavior is as expected:

```
samm$ ./a.out -h
Options:
  -h [ --help ]         produce help message
  --foo arg             set foo

boost version: 1_44
samm$ ./a.out --help
Options:
  -h [ --help ]         produce help message
  --foo arg             set foo

boost version: 1_44
samm$ ./a.out --foo 1
samm$ ./a.out --asdf
unknown option asdf
samm$
```

However, I was surprised when introducing a positional argument, it was not flagged as an error

```
samm$ ./a.out foo bar baz
samm$
```

Why is `boost::program_options::too_many_positional_options_error` exception not thrown?

Comment: My guess is that unless there is a leading `-` or `--`, things are considered as arguments, not options.

Comment: @Arun, that behavior isn't explicitly clear in the documentation. I've sort of found a solution in my answer below, though it still seems counter-intuitive to me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

when I explicitly indicate no positional options are supported:

```
    const po::positional_options_description p; // note empty positional options
    po::store(
            po::command_line_parser( argc, argv).
                      options( desc ).
                      positional( p ).
                      run(),
                      vm
                      );
```

I get the expected behavior:

```
samm$ ./a.out asdf foo bar
too many positional options
samm$
```

Comment: Just came to the same conclusion myself. It seems a bit odd that you have to explicitly state that you _don't_ want positional arguments. It would make more sense to assume that anything that isn't explicitly asked for isn't wanted.